# Handling 150 million rows with R and SQL

Tags: sql, r, dataframe

I am running queries against an SQL Server through R trying to get the sum of values per columns "ID" and "ProductCode" for the last 60 days by grouping. The total expected number of rows is ID * ProductCode * Dates, e.g. 33 IDs * 76.000 ProductCodes * 60 Dates, resulting in around 150 million rows. Do you have any suggestions on how to handle such amounts of data as this needs at least 1 hour to execute?

```
    for(date in 1:nrow(dates)) {
      mydf <- dbGetQuery(con, 
             paste("SELECT ID, ProductCode, sum(Value) AS Value
             FROM DBO.Value
             WHERE Number NOT IN (100) AND ", 
             "'", dates[date, 1], "'", "BETWEEN ValidFrom AND ISNULL(ValidTo, '2099-12-31')
             Group by ID, ProductCode", sep = ""))
      
      if(nrow(mydf) != 0) {
         mydf$Date <- dates[date, 1]
         result <- rbind(result, mydf)
      } else {
         next
      }
}
```

Comment: My first thought is to change the `for` loop to an `lapply` and move the `rbind` outside the loop.  That means you bind the rows only once in total, rather than once for each unique `date`.  Binding is *slow*...  And shouldn't both references to `dates[date, 1]` be simply `date`?  You seem to be executing the same query multiple times and then duplicating the result once for each unique value in `dates`...

Comment: @Limey, I think `date` is an integer indexing the row of `dates`, so assuming that `dates` is a simple `data.frame` (and not `tbl_df` or `data.table`), then `dates[date,1]` likely returns something like a `Date`-class object.

Comment: @r2evans.  That's very plausible.  But the very fact we are having this discussion suggests that the clarity of the original post could be improved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can be done in a single query, and a bit more efficiently. My trick here is to upload (into a temporary table) the dates you want, then do a join on a date range.

### Reproducible sample data

I'll start by generating some fake data. Note that I confound `ID` and `ProductCode` here, but it is only to have both columns in this sample. The query should still work as-is.

You should not need to run this portion yourself unless you want to play with "my data". Otherwise, change my `mytable` to `DBO.Value` (and perhaps other changes I missed).

```r
set.seed(42)
n <- 1000
mytable <- transform(
  data.frame(
    ID = sample(LETTERS[1:7], size = n, replace = TRUE),
    Value = sample(1e3, size = n, replace = TRUE),
    ValidFrom = Sys.Date() - sample(365, size = n, replace = TRUE)
  ),
  ProductCode = ID,
  ValidTo = ValidFrom + sample(99, size = n, replace = TRUE))
mytable$ValidTo[runif(n) > 0.9] <- NA
head(mytable)
#   ID Value  ValidFrom ProductCode    ValidTo
# 1  A   190 2022-01-26           A 2022-04-25
# 2  E   792 2021-02-08           E       <NA>
# 3  A   293 2022-01-23           A 2022-04-26
# 4  A   314 2022-01-19           A 2022-04-13
# 5  B   339 2021-03-15           B 2021-04-09
# 6  D   596 2021-02-12           D 2021-05-01

# conss <- DBI::dbConnect(...)
DBI::dbExecute(conss, "drop table if exists mytable")
DBI::dbWriteTable(conss, "mytable", mytable, create = TRUE)
DBI::dbGetQuery(conss, "select top 3 * from mytable")
```

Now I have a table `mytable` on the database with 1000 rows.

### Single query

The first step for simplicity is to put the table of 60 dates into a temporary table. I'll call it `#mydates`. (The `#` in SQL Server denotes a temporary table that will be automatically removed when this connection is closed. This is not required, but a good practice ... and it will keep your DBAs happy.)

(This part you *do* need to do, it is not part of my reproducible sample. That is, using your dates, not mine.)

```r
mydates <- data.frame(date = Sys.Date() - 0:59)
head(mydates)
#         date
# 1 2022-01-31
# 2 2022-01-30
# 3 2022-01-29
# 4 2022-01-28
# 5 2022-01-27
# 6 2022-01-26
DBI::dbExecute(conss, "drop table if exists #mydates")
# [1] 0
DBI::dbWriteTable(conss, "#mydates", mydates, create = TRUE)
```

From here, let's run a single query:

```r
ret <- DBI::dbGetQuery(conss,
  "select myd.date,
     myt.ID, myt.ProductCode, sum(myt.Value) as Value
   from #mydates myd
     left join mytable myt on
       (myd.date between myt.ValidFrom and myt.ValidTo
          or
        myt.ValidFrom <= myd.date and myt.ValidTo is null)
   group by myt.ID, myt.ProductCode, myd.date")

nrow(ret)
# [1] 420

head(ret)
#         date ID ProductCode Value
# 1 2021-12-03  A           A 14563
# 2 2021-12-04  A           A 14563
# 3 2021-12-05  A           A 14563
# 4 2021-12-06  A           A 14557
# 5 2021-12-07  A           A 14963
# 6 2021-12-08  A           A 14963
```

This looks right, as the number of rows returned is what we expect and your description of how many rows you expect out of this:

```r
length(unique(mytable$ID)) * # currently same as $ProductCode
  nrow(mydates)
# [1] 420
```

### Verification/Validation

We can do the aggregation here in R to verify that the results are as expected. Because this is a range-join, I will use `data.table` to demonstrate; `dplyr`+`fuzzyjoin` or `sqldf` can do it, it's a bit more difficult in base R.

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(mytable)
setDT(mydates)

ret2 <- mydates[, origdate := date   # b/c data.table overwrites 'date' with 'ValidFrom' in the join
                ][ mytable, on = .(date >= ValidFrom)
                  ][ is.na(ValidTo) | origdate <= ValidTo,
                    ][, .(Value = sum(Value)), by = .(origdate, ID, ProductCode) ]
setorder(ret2, origdate, ID)
setnames(ret2, "origdate", "date")

all.equal(ret, ret2, check.attributes = FALSE)
# [1] TRUE
cbind(head(ret), head(ret2))
#         date ID ProductCode Value       date ID ProductCode Value
# 1 2021-12-03  A           A 14563 2021-12-03  A           A 14563
# 2 2021-12-03  B           B 19062 2021-12-03  B           B 19062
# 3 2021-12-03  C           C 13993 2021-12-03  C           C 13993
# 4 2021-12-03  D           D 15836 2021-12-03  D           D 15836
# 5 2021-12-03  E           E 17181 2021-12-03  E           E 17181
# 6 2021-12-03  F           F  9857 2021-12-03  F           F  9857
```

### PS: download speeds

FYI, downloading 150 million rows over `DBI` is going to be rather slow. I strongly suggest using `sqlcmd` or `bcp` to do a bulk-query, as your download times will be significantly shorter. Crafting that command-line is a bit out-of-scope for this answer, but the docs are fairly decent. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-migrate-bcp.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for this promising answer! I will try this out and keep you updated.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temporary table in `SQL Server` (60 rows according to your post).

The date column shouldn't be called `date` because this would interfere with `SQL` syntax, let's assume it's called `EventDate` :

```
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(...)

# Create temporary table
dbWriteTable(con,'#DATES',dates)

mydf <- dbGetQuery(con, 
             "SELECT EventDate, ID, ProductCode, sum(Value) AS Value
             FROM DBO.Value,#DATES
             WHERE Number NOT IN (100) AND 
             EventDate BETWEEN ValidFrom AND ISNULL(ValidTo, '2099-12-31')
             Group by EventDate,ID, ProductCode")

# Remove temporary table
dbExecute(con,"DROP TABLE #DATES" )
```